# QGIS: NetCDF file not aligned with OpenStreetMap

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, netcdf

I want to show a 2m height temperature layer that covers most of Canada and northern United States. The data itself is initially a .grib2 file obtainable from the Gov of Canada free public weather data. I converted it into NetCDF because I heard it was easier to manipulate this way.

I'm very new to everything GIS related, and I just want to see how the 2m map stacks up on a basic global map, which I decided to be OpenStreetMap.

The coordinate reference system of the 2m layer is originally in EPSG:4326 - WSG 84 while the coordinate reference system of OpenStreetMap is originally EPSG:3857-WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator.

I set the OpenStreetMap to the reference system of the 2m temp map and succeed in having both layers showing. However, the 2m temp map appears centered on OpenStreetMap instead of being on Canada/North US.

Here is a print screen of the two layers: [image]

And also a description of the 2m height map : [image]

Could anybody be able to explain to me what is going on?

EDIT: 
I've attempted to use the GRIB2 file itself instead of the Netcdf. When uploading to qgis, the GRIB2 file arrives with the following custom projection:
Generated CRS (+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=60 +lon_0=252 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6371229 +b=6371229 +units=m +no_defs)

I cannot get OSM to match this projection, but if I change the GRIB2 file to match OSM's projection (EPSG 3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator) I receive something similar to what's happening with the converted Netcdf.

GDAL allows me to get info on the Netcdf file. Here is what I receive

[image]

Comment: GRIB is a supported file type in QGIS.  What happens if you add your GRIB to a new QGIS project?  Ensure On-the-fly projection is checked, and add your OSM data.  https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/index.html

Comment: You didn't include the data spatial extent in the screenshot. Right now, it's showing up as if it's still raw cell values--LL corner is at 0,0. Does the metadata show the correct lat/lon extents? Is it georeferenced?

Comment: @GBG I am using QGIS 3.6.3 and it seems like On-the-fly projection is enable by default and actually cannot be disable (https://issues.qgis.org/issues/11644). When adding GRIB. For some reason, the GRIB has its own default coordinate system (see edit in post). I can't get OSM to match that same projection, but if I turn the GRIB projection into the OSM projection (ESPG 3857 - WSG 84 / Pseudo-Mercartor) I get something similar to what happens with my Netcdf file.

Comment: @mkennedy Utilizing gdal to get info on the netcdf file, I was able to receive some additional information (see edit). I unfortunately do not know how to make sense of the information, because it seems to be using a lat/lon reference, but the coordinate system seems to indicate numbers in the x and y. I do believe that what its showing me is the raw cell values.